# Creating a select to 'de-normalise' the data within a table

Tags: sql, netezza

I put the work de-normalise in quote marks, because it might not be the right way of putting it, but not too sure how else to describe it...

I have the following table

```
Source   Priority   Attribute
A        1          Name
B        2          Name
C        3          Name
A        1          Address
B        2          Address
C        3          Address
A        2          Email
B        3          Email
C        1          Email
```

I would like my select to return:

```
Source Name_Pri  Addr_Pri  Email_Pri
A      1         1         2
B      2         2         3
C      3         3         1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a pivot.  I often do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select source,
       max(case when attribute = 'Name' then priority end) as name_priority,
       max(case when attribute = 'Address' then priority end) as address_priority,
       max(case when attribute = 'Email' then priority end) as email_priority
from t
group by source;
```